# Django creating sessions

Tags: python, django, session

I have a existing Django application where the sessions middleware is enabled.

When I look into the code I don't see any place where a session is explicitly save'd(like below) to create a new session.

```
request.session['foo'] = 'bar'
```

Even though its not save'd explicitly I still see a session object being created once the user is created.

Is it possible the session is created once the user is created. The application is using django allauth for authentication.

When I decode my session object, this is how it looks..

```
{u'_auth_user_backend': u'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 u'_auth_user_hash': u'df0df84cd5f03676a8756c06fbe6816b9082773d',
 u'_auth_user_id': 21,
 u'otp_device_id': u'two_factor.models.PhoneDevice/30',
 u'wizard_login_view':
     {u'extra_data': {},
      u'step': None,
      u'step_data': {},
      u'step_files': {},
      u'validated_step_data': {}}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "saved"?

Comment: Its meant that its created and not saved

Answer (score 0):

Post create signal is good for this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore

def write_session(sender, **kw):
    s = SessionStore()
    s['foo']="bar"
    s.save()
    s.session_key # gives '2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead'
    s = SessionStore(session_key='2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead')
    s['foo'] # gives "bar"

post_save.connect(write_session, sender=User, dispatch_uid="users-writesession-signal")
```

Comment: Where do you take a request in write_session?

Comment: It does not need to take request.It is not a view. Basically write_session will receive a signal when something will create a user.

Comment: Yes, but you write `request.session['foo'] = 'bar'` in write_session, which not contains request.

Comment: Sorry, i've changed code to fit your needs. here is a doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/